# Understanding data types and attributes values

Tags: categories, numeric, numerical-methods, data-analysis, categorical-data

I would like to understand the following data types and attributes values for the following data , understanding it can make correct decision to select classification or clustering algorithm .

my data consist of 100 folders which contain images in each one , so I selected some content to categorical these images based on its content 
like { sea , sky , lion ....etc }

```
                              categorical- attributes 

folder-name    total images      sea         sky      food     animals   
folder1            100            10          2        0         5
folder2            20             0           1        15        3   
etc.
```

total images refer to total images in that folder , number in each category vectors are the frequency of that images found in each folder , for example sea picture are found in folder 1 10 ( 10 images are sea photo) etc..

I know the values here are discrete , but what is the attributes { interval , nominal , ordinal } 
value has been grouped based on simple comparing is folder1.image1=sea if yes then 1 otherwise is 0 then I have grouped the image values to declare the above table , 
in case to convert frequency values to ordinal , calculating frequency percentage if its 10% then is 1 , 20% then is 2 is this way correct , 
any advices thanks .

Comment: It depends on what you looking for. You can apply simple percentage approach and cluster by amount of similar terms (files) in document (folder). You can either apply more complicated mechanism such as tf-idf to spot rare terms (files) and cluster documents (folders) accordingly

Comment: can I apply TF.IDF for this kind of data set like documents , my goal to cluster similar documents that share most of these attributes , like can give me cluster 1 { folder1 , folder10 } class sea+animals

Comment: or can give me clusters for folders that has most frequency attributes , like cluster1 = { folder1 , folder 2...folder10 } which has sea photos , any idea please

Comment: You can either cluster by simple percentage, lets say you set threshold on 10%, then rank by percentage of terms in the documents and cluster accordingly or you can implement more sophisticated (but not necessarily more accurate) mechanism that clusters according to tf-idf. Let's say you have two documents with the same very rare term, thus these documents go to the same cluster. I would start with a simplest approcah

Comment: thanks for that , rely you are help me , so can I consider 10% is an 1 , 20% is 2 ..etc then selected threshold for example 10% , and applying categorical clustering algorithm , what do you think appropriate algorithms can work better , I'm looking for CLIQUE , ENCLUS , or grid based algorithms , subspace clustering algorithm , spectral , what do you think which one better ?

Comment: can you make your explanation as brief answer to voted it , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comments you implement different approaches to cluster:

1. Euclidean distance (lets say spot 10% most frequent terms and build the space accordingly (X .. n axis) and them measure the distance between documents (folders)
2. Jaccard index
3. CLIQUE looks interesting, but I'm not enough familiar with it.
4. tf-idf is good for spotting non-frequent terms (files) and claim that documents that has these terms are similar and belong to the same class.

As I mentioned before I would start with something really simple like ranking by terms or Euclidean distance to "feel" the data. As you proceed you get more ideas

Comment: So my data is categorical attributes , and values are become ordinal { 10% , 20 % ... 100% } , so if I consider each frequency may I got fraction like 11% , 12 % can I binning it like { 0-10 % } is 1 , 10-20% is 2 so in this case may I got frequency attributes values

Comment: The simplest thing for the very beginning is rank by terms (files). Let's say FolderA's 30% files are "sea", 20% are "sky" and 12% are "food" (10% is a threshold). That's your ranking for Folder A {"sea";"sky";"food"}. See if have other folders with similar ranking. This is the simplest model. You can do it in a flash. Next try Euclidean distance based on the same approach.

Comment: thanks ,  finally , each category is an dimension so for my data is 4 dimension , if I increased category by 3 its become 7 dimension , so what is my attributes data type { ordinal , interval , scale ..} to explore the algorithms that deal with that data types , thanks

Comment: If you address "sea", "sky", "food", "animals" as dimensions, therefore your data type is nominal. Have a look: http://www.mymarketresearchmethods.com/types-of-data-nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio/

Comment: thanks , you help me more , in future when you know good algorithms can work with this data set please inform me , I will try some kinds of it , thanks again